# Objective c swipe a series of buttons left and right to reveal more buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am very much new to iOS coding and Objective c. I am developing an App for learning it.
The app is from Github which i am modifying. The user can draw on the screen and can use different colors to select the pen color and can also erase the whole drawing. But i do not have much space on the mobile screen.

I was searching for something that allows me to slide a series of buttons to the left and right with swipe so i can have a lot more color for the user to chose from.

Here is an snapshot

[image]

As of now i can fit 5 colors and one erase all button. (Sorry about the GUI). I want let the users to slide the button left to righ to reveal more buttons.

There is somthing that can be done with table cell (from Github)
https://github.com/MortimerGoro/MGSwipeTableCell
[image]
But i do not want to use tableview.

Is there a library where i can do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at UIScrollView. It will allow you to have more colors available and s very easy to to use.

You can have it free scroll, or have paging, which means it snaps to a page, similar to how the Photos app works.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/reference/uiscrollview_class/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Gary, 
I did find a library that did exactly what i wanted

Link : http://code4app.net/ios/LTInfiniteScrollView/54732343e24741f423b03ca0

[image]

Comment: No worries. I would recommend also trying out a basic scroll view yourself as it will help to get to grips with the language.